# Show that the summation is bounded by O(1)

Tags: algorithms

How could I show that the following summation is O(1)?

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^2}{2^i}\
\end{equation}

I know that the idea is to find a geometric series approaching a constant by which it is bounded, but I am having trouble finding one that would fit.

Comment: Maybe use $i^2\le 2^{i/2}$ if $i\ge 16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this could be of interest to you : the value of the summation is just

6 - (n^2 + 4 n + 6) / 2^n

If fact, the summation of i^k/k^i (i=1 to n) leads to some simple formulas. Thanks for having asked this question. I had interesting time working around it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You could use the ratio test to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2}{2^k}$$

converges.